# how to insert variable into string by position

Tags: python, string, variables, position

How to insert a variable into a string by position,
For example, insert `a` in `string`

`string = "Hello World"`

`a = '@'`

`position = 3`

output >>> Hel@lo World

Comment: Have you tried something? What went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: `string[:position] + a + string[position:]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use slicings:

```
a = '@'
position = 3
string = "Hello World"
new = string[:position] + a + string[position:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_1="Hello World"
st=list(str_1)
st.insert(pos,a)
str_1="".join(st)
```

you could first convert the list into characters which will be stored in a list in which u can add as many elements as u like and then finally get the modified string by using .join()

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
str_1 = "Hello World"

def insert_str(org_str, insert_str, pos):
    str_2 = list(org_str)
    str_2.insert(pos, insert_str)
    new_string = "".join(str_2)
    return new_string

a = '@'
position = 3

new_string = insert_str(org_str=str_1, insert_str=a, pos=position)
print(new_string)
```